# What is the name of this element?

Tags: android

I am trying to make my first app for android and I need to know the name of this element:

[image]

Comment: It's a Widget...not sure if it has a more specific name than that, but I'm sure someone can provide more insight than me. :)

Comment: Not sure if that widget has a specific name, maybe setting/preference widget?

Answer (score 4):

That is what's called a widget on the Android OS.

See the Android Developer site for more details: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Answer (score 3):

It is a Widget. This particular Widget is simpy named "powermanager" on my Nexus S. 
If you want to read more about Widgets read this [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/package-summary.html) and this [dev-guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)